# cellRendererParams Ag-Grid 19 and Angular 6. Call function of my component

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have in my Ag-grid column a column in which I have inserted a component, that pusal calls me to a function of my controller.

I get to my controller without problem, but when trying to call another function of my controller, I can not, because when I put this, it does not refer to my controller, but to the ag-grid component.

// COMPONENT

```
this.columnDefs = [{
  headerName: '',
  width: 50,
  cellRendererFramework: ActionCellRendererComponent,
  cellRendererParams: {
    icon: 'fa-trash',
    action: this.downloadAttachmentAction
  }
},



downloadAttachmentAction(params: any) {
   this.otherFunction() <-- I can not do the functions of my controller. with "this" as it refers to ag-grid
}

otherFunction(){
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a context issue, the downloadAttachmentAction is called by ag grid and hence the context is ag-gird instance, what you need to do is change the context when that function is invoked, bind function help us do this, change how the downloadAttachmentAction is being used from:

```
    action: this.downloadAttachmentAction
```

to

```
    action: this.downloadAttachmentAction.bind(this)
```

Comment: this did not work for me, where the only difference in my case is not controller function but I have a call to service from my otherFunction() which reads from local file and I want to delete an object from the file which matches my param.node.data, but I see undefined when I read from the file in the otherFunction() as mentioned above.